# Conditional Logic about limit points

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space. Let $E'$ denote the set of all limit points of $E$.

I know that if $E' \neq \emptyset$, then $E$ is infinite. Is this statement equivalent to if $E$ is finite, then $E' = \emptyset$? Can someone point me to a source on logic that discusses this? I am very weak when it comes to logic.

Comment: Yes, this is correct: it’s the contrapositive of the original implication. In general terms, the implication $\varphi\to\psi$ is logically equivalent to the impllcation $\neg\psi\to\neg\varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

To give a formal logical proof of @Brian Scott's statement, a.k.a, the contrapositive ,we have :

Assume $ A \rightarrow B$. We show (by way of contradiction) that $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (\ - B \rightarrow - A )$.

So, we have:

1) $A \rightarrow B$ , by assumption

2) $-B $ , by assumption

we make another assumption

3) $A$ , assumption , and we conclude :

4) $B$ , from 1,3, using MP

5) $B$ & $ -B $   from 2, 4

6) Contradiction, we conclude $-A$

We discharge our assumption from line 2 , to conclude:

7) $-B \rightarrow -A$

We now discharge the initial assumption to get :

8) $ ( A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (-B \rightarrow -A) $